# Autonomous Loop channel

Tags: lightning-network, ln-channel-balance-management, ln-loop

Can I have an autonomous loop channel with myself where I would suck all excess inbound/outbound capacity to/from channels I have with other parties? In such a case, I would not have to even burden Bitcoin blockchain with the looping activity.

Comment: Could you elaborate how a channel would be able to buffer for all other channels? Do you for example propose to have a wumbo channel between two nodes you control with large balances on both sides?

Comment: I thought about it and I came to the same conclusion as you, to have two nodes I control and big channel between. My first naive thought that lead me to pose the question would require a channel with three parties connected to it where I would represent two parties and the third party would be a node of others for connection to the LN.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can rebalance your channels by creating circular onions. That will also cost you routing fees which are currently low.

However in order to get onchain funds you would have to close a channel (or open a channel if you want more liquidity). This means you cannot really swap on chain with off chain funds to provide yourself with inbound liquidity - wich is what loop / submarine swaps are for.

If you use c Lightning you can use the rebalce plugin https://github.com/lightningd/plugins/tree/master/rebalance or the drain plugin: https://github.com/lightningd/plugins/tree/master/drain depending on what exactly you want to do you might have to fork these plugins